# Unable to connect to heroku psql database using the command heroku pg:psql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I have a backend node.js app setup in Heroku that uses a postgreSQL database. I have connected it to my github repo and can push my code to heroku fine it seems. I have installed the Heroku Postgres add-on, but for some reason I am unable to access the database using the heroku pg:psql command. When I run the command, it just states `Connecting to databasename` and no error or anything else pops up. Here are my gitbash commands:

```
olms2@LAPTOP-O3KD6RL5 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Springboard/Current VS Code Projects/final-capstone-2-backend (master)
$ heroku addons

Add-on                                           Plan       Price  State
ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇ  ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇ  ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇ  ΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇΓöÇ
heroku-postgresql (postgresql-elliptical-01419)  hobby-dev  free   created
 ΓööΓöÇ as DATABASE

The table above shows add-ons and the attachments to the current app (freebay-backend) or other apps.


olms2@LAPTOP-O3KD6RL5 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Springboard/Current VS Code Projects/final-capstone-2-backend (master)
$ heroku pg:psql
--> Connecting to postgresql-elliptical-01419
```

On a side note, I have no idea why the `heroku addons` command shows all that gibberish. I have tried deleting the entire app then reinstalling, but I still get the gibberish and unresponsive `heroku pg:psql`. I should mention that I created the app and installed the addon on the heroku website interface.

Seems there are a bunch of StackOverflow Answers referencing an error with the pg:psql command, but couldn't find any confronting an issue with the command not responding. Happy to provide more info and would really appreciate any help.